# Tableu Server Client unable to update filters in a view before downloading as CSV

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have been trying to download a view as csv after changing the view filter but I have not been successful in applying the right filter.

I am using TableauServerClient in Python library to establish the task. Could some one please let me know what I am missing?

Below is the code I am using - I have tried different  formats of date to no avail. There are other filters in the view but I just want to change the date and extract csv.

```
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
 csv_req_option = TSC.CSVRequestOptions()
 csv_req_option.vf("Reporting Date","06/30/2023")
 view = server.views.get_by_id('4d83f853-3d59-44e5-8fc2-8dcae84dbfa0')
 server.views.populate_csv(view,req_options = csv_req_option)
 with open('./view_data_filter.csv', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(b''.join(view.csv))
```

Comment: You can [pass filters through your URL string](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_structure.htm) first and then download the view as a csv.